Hypothesis check: The graph of a bounded function on $(0, 1)$ is not closed
Consider the following problem:

Let $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and bounded function. Prove that the graph $\Gamma(f)$ of $f$,
$$
\Gamma(f) = \left\lbrace (x, f(x)) \mid x\in (0, 1) \right\rbrace
$$
is not a closed set.

I have already solved it but without using the hypothesis $f$ is continuous. So I was wondering if it's necessary or I made some mistake in my solution. Can you help me to see if my proof is correct, please? Here it is:
My proof (without using continuity):
Let $f: (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function (not necessarily continuous).
Consider the sequence $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. The sequence $\left\lbrace f(a_n) \right\rbrace$ is bounded, so it has a convergent subsequence, say $f(a_{n_k})$. Let $l$ be its limit. We claim that the point $(0, l)$ is a limit point of $\Gamma(f)$.
For given $\epsilon > 0$, there is $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for $k>K$, $\left\lvert f(a_{n_k}) - l\right\rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 2}$ and $a_{n_k} < \frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt 2}$.
This implies that, for $k>K$, $\lVert (0, l) - (a_{n_k},  f(a_{n_k}))\rVert < \epsilon$.
Therefore, $(0, l)$ is a limit point of $\Gamma(f)$, but since it doesn't belong to it, we conclude that $\Gamma(f)$ is not closed.

Your proof is correct, hence the continuity hypothesis is useless.
